# Querying an array of arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

Say, I have a document like this..

```
"ID" : "fruit1",
"Keys" : [["apple", "carrot", "banana"]]
```

How do I query for Keys = "carrot". None of the following syntax works.

```
db.myColl.results.find({ "Keys" : "carrot" });
db.myColl.results.find({ "Keys" : [["carrot"]] });
```

Following works though, but not helpful.

```
db.myColl.results.find({ "Keys" : [["apple", "carrot", "banana]]});
```

Any pointer to this query will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I think your best bet is to change your schema.  Documents with arrays of arrays aren't well supported by Mongo.

Comment: @JohnnyHK, its quite possible in mongo to query nested arrays. check out my answer

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Interesting question, This will do the trick

```
 db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['carrot']}}}})
```

`$elemMatch` used to check if an element in an array matches the specified match expression.
so nested `$elemMatch` will go deeper into nested arrays

Test data

```
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : [["apple", "carrot", "banana"]]})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : [["apple", "orange", "banana"]]})


db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['carrot']}}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506555212aeb79b5f7374cbf"), "ID" : "fruit1", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "carrot", "banana" ] ] }

db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['banana']}}}})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("506555212aeb79b5f7374cbf"), "ID" : "fruit1", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "carrot", "banana" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5065587e2aeb79b5f7374cc0"), "ID" : "fruit2", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "orange", "banana" ] ] }
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't $elemMatch only return the first result, rendering your "banana" example incorrect?

Comment: @RyanWheale, i don't get it. $elemMatch returns all records matching the given condition, not just the first one. In the banana example, it does return 2 records. you can check the ids

Comment: My bad.  Using `$elemMatch` for **projection** only returns one result.  Using it in a query will return multiple results as you would expect. Lack of sleep is getting to me...

Comment: Alternatively consider using an array of subdocument of array.
    db.multiArrTest.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : [{"array" : ["apple", "carrot", "banana"]}, {"array": ["a", "b", "c"]}]})
    db.multiArrTest.find({'Keys.array': "carrot"})

Comment: I have an scenario, where I need to find sub documents. could I able to find it using the $elemMatch ? My data schema some thing like this

{
   "id" : 1,
   "data: {
       "user": [
           {
              'id' : 1,
              'name' : ABC,
           },
          {
              'id' : 2,
              'name' : ABC,
           },
           {
              'id' : 3,
              'name' : ABC,
           },
       ]
    }
}

Need to find get the object where the user's id =3; Can someone help me to sort this ?

Comment: @RameshVel Do you know how to update `carrot` when we don't know indexOf  `carrot` ?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to find array of first position data, use 0 as reference index to get data in nested array.

```
db.getCollection('routes').find({"routeId" : 12,'routes._id':ObjectId("598da27a713f3e6acd72287f"),'routes.0.stops.0.orders.0._id':ObjectId("598da27a713f3e6acd722887")})
```

Comment: Or if you want to search at 4. array index: { "firstLevel.3": {$elemMatch: {$eq:22}}}

Answer (score -1):

> "merchant_id": [
> {
> "id": "63fa3cd15595d06245a950ed"
> },
> {
> "id": "63fa3cd15595d06245a950ed"
> }
> ],

## { merchant_id: { $elemMatch: { id: merchant } } }

Comment: it is not array of arrays