# Updating values in nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12636038/11792 to be very helpful to me how to query nested arrays. What I want now is to be able to update (push or replace) a value in the nested array. For example I want to replace all the "apple" values with "peach".

```
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : [["apple", "carrot", "banana"]]})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : [["apple", "orange", "banana"]]})
```

I found 3 more questions about updating nested arrays but their answers do not seem to be helpful in this case. So how do we modify the values in the inner array?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is `findAndyModify`. [See the documentation here.](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

Basically, you can include a query, remove an item, and update the document in one go. For example, if you want to:

1. Find all documents with 'apple' in the `Keys` subdocument
2. Remove all instances of 'apple'
3. Add 'peach' at the end of the array

It might look something like this:

```
db.multiArr.findAndModify({
    query: { Keys : 'apple' },
    update: { $pull : { Keys : 'apple' }}, { $push : { Keys : 'peach' }},
    new: true
});
```

EDIT:

[The above looks like it should work, but you can't use `$push` and `$pull` together in one update](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1050). It produces this error message:

```
findAndModifyFailed failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: Field name duplication not allowed with modifiers",
    "code" : 10150,
    "ok" : 0
} at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:399
```

You're just going to have to do it in two updates:

```
// $push first or you won't be able to find the documents
db.multiArr.update({ Keys : 'apple' }, { $push : { Keys : 'peaches' }}, { multi : true });
db.multiArr.update({ Keys : 'apple' }, { $pull : { Keys : 'apple' }}, { multi : true });
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer, if you know the index of 'apple', you may hard code as below:

```
db.multiArr.update({Keys:"apple"}, {$set: {"Keys.0":"peaches"}}, {multi:true})
```