# MongoDB $pop element which is in 3 time nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, jagged-arrays

Here is the data structure for each document in the collection. The datastructure is fixed.

```
{
  '_id': 'some-timestamp',
  'RESULT': [ 
              {
               'NUMERATION': [ // numeration of divisions
                    {
                                      // numeration of producttypes
                       'DIVISIONX': [{'PRODUCTTYPE': 'product xy', COUNT: 100}] 
                    }
                ]
              }
            ]
}
```

The query result should be in the same structure but only contain producttypes matching a `regular expression`.

I tried using an nested `$elemMatch`operator but this doesn't get me any closer. **I don't know how I can iterate each value in the producttypes array for each division. 
How can I do that?** Then I could apply `$pop`, `$in` and `$each`.

I looked at:

- [Querying an array of arrays in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629692/querying-an-array-of-arrays-in-mongodb#45754937)
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/each/
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pop/

... and more

The solution I want to avoid is writing something like this:
`collection.find().forEach(function(x) { /* more for eaches */ })`

**Edit:** 
Here is an example document to copy:

```
{"_id":"5ab550d7e85d5930b0879cbe","RESULT":[{"NUMERATION":[{"DIVISION":[{"PRODUCTTYPE":"Book","COUNT":10},{"PRODUCTTYPE":"Giftcard","COUNT":"300"}]}]}]}
```

E.g. the query result should only return the entry with the giftcard:

```
{"_id":"5ab550d7e85d5930b0879cbe","RESULT":[{"NUMERATION":[{"DIVISION":[{"PRODUCTTYPE":"Giftcard","COUNT":"300"}]}]}]}
```

Comment: Please post sample data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `forEach` approach the result is in the correct format. I'm still looking for a better way which does not involve the use of that function - therefore **I will not mark this as an answer**.

But for now this works fine:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(
    function(wholeDocument) {
        wholeDocument['RESULT'].forEach(function (resultEntry) {
                    resultEntry['NUMERATION'].forEach(function (numerationEntry) {
                        numerationEntry['DIVISION'].forEach(function(divisionEntry, index) {
                            // example condition (will be replaced by regular expression evaluation)
                            if(divisionEntry['PRODUCTTYPE'] != 'Giftcard'){
                                numerationEntry['DIVISION'].splice(index, 1);
                             }
                        })
                    })
                })
                print(wholeDocument);
    }
)
```

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Rahul Raj's comments I have read up the aggregation with the `$redact` operator. A prototype of the solution to the issue is this query:

```
db.getCollection('DeepStructure').aggregate( [
  { $redact: {
                 $cond: {
                     if: { $ne: [ "$PRODUCTTYPE", "Giftcard" ] },
                     then: "$$DESCEND",
                     else: "$$PRUNE"
                 }
             }
  }
  ]
)
```

Comment: The only way I can think of is to come up with an aggregation query with some sort of `$redact` query on it. That might be the only way to keep the original document structure, otherwise just do projection followed by unwinding the array & then apply match conditions

Comment: @RahulRaj Thanks, the `$redact` aggregation seems very promising.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you're trying to `update` nested array. 
You need to use positional operators `$[]` or `$` for that.
If you use `$[]`, you will be able to remove all matching nested array elements.
And if you use `$`, only the first matching array element will get removed. 
Use `$regex` operator to pass on your regular expression.

Also, you need to use `$pull` to remove array elements based on matching condition. In your case, its regular expression. Note that `$elemMatch` is not the correct one to use with `$pull` as arguments to `$pull` are direct queries to the array.

```
db.collection.update(
 {/*additional matching conditions*/},
 {$pull: {"RESULT.$[].NUMERATION.$[].DIVISIONX":{PRODUCTTYPE: {$regex: "xy"}}}},
 {multi: true}

 )
```

Just replace `xy` with your regular expression and add your own matching conditions as required. I'm not quite sure about your data set, but I came up with the above answer based on my assumptions from the given info. Feel free to change according to your requirements.

Comment: I'm sry updating the collection is not an option. The result of the query should not be written to the database. I updated the question with an example document and result which I'm trying to accomplish.