# MongoDB ScalaDriver Query for nested array

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have been troubled by nested arrays in mongodb, and as soon as I have found a same question here in stackoverflow, I tried it out and worked on `mongo shell`. But now my problem is how to convert the said code to scala version using `mongo scala driver`. I would be delighted and happy for any ideas and answers.

Here is the test data. I will still use the same data as the one on the previous post.

```
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit1","Keys" : [["apple", "carrot", "banana"]]})
db.multiArr.insert({"ID" : "fruit2","Keys" : [["apple", "orange", "banana"]]})


db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['carrot']}}}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("506555212aeb79b5f7374cbf"), "ID" : "fruit1", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "carrot", "banana" ] ] }

db.multiArr.find({'Keys':{$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['banana']}}}})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("506555212aeb79b5f7374cbf"), "ID" : "fruit1", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "carrot", "banana" ] ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5065587e2aeb79b5f7374cc0"), "ID" : "fruit2", "Keys" : [ [ "apple", "orange", "banana" ] ] }
```

I know this will be a redundant post. But since the question was answered by 2012, I cannot see any hope of having any reply to my question if I post it there.

this is the link for the previous question: [Querying an array of arrays in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629692/querying-an-array-of-arrays-in-mongodb)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Ossip I have tried many things just to have this thing work out in `mongo-scala-driver` but I have failed since I was only using `Filters` from them, not knowing the answer below was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the mongo-scala-driver then,

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import org.mongodb.scala._

// if you have a connections string
val mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
  .applyConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017")
  .build()

// if you have a cluster and ip's of the nodes
val servers = List("xx.xx.xx.xx", "xx.xx.xx.xx")
val serverAddresses = mongoConfig.servers.map(s => new ServerAddress(s)).asJava
val mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
  .applyToClusterSettings(b => b.hosts(serverAddresses))
  .build()

val mongoClient = MongoClient(mongoClientSettings)

val mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("your-database-name")

val mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("multiArr")

val documentsFuture: Future[List[Document]] = mongoCollection.find(Document(
  "Keys" -> Document(
    "$elemMatch" -> Document(
      "$elemMatch" -> Document("$in" -> List("carrot"))
    )
  )
).toFuture
```

And now you have the future containing the list of your documents, I hope you can do the rest.

Comment: I have tried this solution and it worked, the one thing that I did wrong was that I only used `org.mongodb.scala.model.Filters._` for the `elemMatch`. Thank you so much @sarvesh-kumar-singh for the answer, it clarified my thoughts on this one.