# MongoDB request for deep field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, request

I have to request the field "type" and I can't find right syntax..[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.find({
  "conditions_object": {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        type: "PORT"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RdSIPd4vnWd) | [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12636038/3710490)