# MongoDB query two dimensional array of ObjectId

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, objectid

I have a collection named Teachers on MongoDB with some documents, here is an example:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("63a89cdae570d47034c996ec"),  
"teachingCategories" : [ 
    [ 
        ObjectId("63a40c7e54351f6071b25abd"), 
        ObjectId("63a65195075c0031b1bd2e81")
    ], 
    [ 
        ObjectId("63a40b4654351f6071b25a82"), 
        ObjectId("63a41d5d54351f6071b25acf"), 
        ObjectId("63a44bdc54351f6071b25b9a")
    ], 
    [ 
        ObjectId("63a40c7e54351f6071b25abd"), 
        ObjectId("63a651d6075c0031b1bd2e87")
    ]
]
```

}

i am trying to find the teachers who have the category id like below

```
db.collection("teachers").find({ teachingCategories: ObjectId("63a44bdc54351f6071b25b9a") })
```

but the mongo db returns nothing

Answer (score 1):

As the `teachingCategories` in your document is `arrays` in `array` you can try something like this

```
db.teachers.find({
  teachingCategories: {
    $elemMatch: {
      $elemMatch: {
        $in: [ObjectId("63a44bdc54351f6071b25b9a")]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Similar question to [Querying an array of arrays in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12629692/querying-an-array-of-arrays-in-mongodb)